# How to fix error when load Json from a server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get a JSON from a server but this error appears in the console:

> You are trying to create a `MonoBehaviour` using the `'new'` keyword.  This is not allowed. `MonoBehaviour`s can only be added using `AddComponent()`. Alternatively, your script can inherit from `ScriptableObject` or no base class at all
>   `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor()`

The JSON is like a list of names, for example

> [“leaderboard01”, “leaderboard02”, …]

This is my code:

```
public class BC_PlayerInfo : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string LeaderboardId = "";

    public BC_PlayerInfo(JsonData jsonData)
    {
        LeaderboardId = SafeGet(jsonData, "leaderboardId");
    }

    private string SafeGet(JsonData jsonData, string key)
    {
        var returnValue = "";

        try
        {
            returnValue = jsonData[key].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

And...

```
private void GetLeaderboadsList()
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    string result = webClient.DownloadString("https://xxxxxxxxx.com/wp-json/vendor/v1/carambolaEventsNames");

    Debug.Log("Usuario creado en la WEB: " + result);

    List<string> leaderboardIds = new List<string>();

    lblist.Clear();

    var leaderboardsList = JsonMapper.ToObject(result);

    foreach (JsonData leaderboardId in leaderboardsList) lblist.Add(new BC_PlayerInfo(leaderboardId));

    foreach (var leaderboardId in lblist)
    {
        string _leaderboardId = leaderboardId.LeaderboardId;
        Debug.Log("LeaderboardName: " + _leaderboardId);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well basically the exception you get tells you ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't instantiate objects that inherit from MonoBehavior, by using this line:

```
lblist.Add(new BC_PlayerInfo(leaderboardId));
```

you are creating a new instance of a Monobehavior, which is not allowed by Unity. See this post for more details: https://answers.unity.com/questions/653904/you-are-trying-to-create-a-monobehaviour-using-the-2.html

As for your solution, does this class really need to inherit from monobehavior? I would just remove that inheritance or create a separate class that does not inherit from monobehavior.

Comment: I have removed MonoBehaviour in the BC_PlayerInfo class and the error has disappeared, but the LeaderboardNames aren't loaded in the foreach

Comment: I have got the solution changing "private string SafeGet(JsonData jsonData, string key)" for "private string SafeGet(JsonData jsonData)". Thank you very much!!